# My TPM version isn't compatible with the windows 11 minimum requirements

Tags: windows, windows-update, tpm, windows-11, windows-11-upgrade

The minimum requirement for Windows 11 is **TPM Version 2.0**, while my version is **1.2**, I think that's why I didn't receive the Windows 11 update.
I found an iso image of it, but is it okay to install it?
I mean what kind of problems I'll face if I did so, thanks.

[image: tpm]

Comment: It simply will not install without TPM 2. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/enable-tpm-2-0-on-your-pc-1fd5a332-360d-4f46-a1e7-ae6b0c90645c

Comment: "is it okay to install it?" - Can you install Windows 11, you might be able to, but your system will be unsupported.  There is a way to bypass the TPM check but, if you avoid that check, you will get into an unsupported state.  **The fact your system does NOT support TPM 2.0 means it also does NOT have a supported processor.**

Comment: [This](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ways-to-install-windows-11-e0edbbfb-cfc5-4011-868b-2ce77ac7c70e) provides those instructions.  However, I strongly advice against, attempting to run Windows 11 on unsupported hardware.

Comment: If your motherboard supports TPM2, then you may be able to upgrade the firmware within the TPM.

Comment: Sigh, you can. I did it on my own one. You can upgrade and downgrade a small number of times. There are instructions and supported firmware if you hunt for them.

Comment: And just for completeness, you can download the firware from `https://www.supermicro.com/wdl/driver/TPM/9665FW update package_1.5.zip`

Comment: If your TPM is 1.2 the CPU generation is likely more than 3 years old. So make sure absolutely everything else is up to snuff (may not be) before you invest in new TPM (if indeed you can even do that).

Comment: "That's why I didn't receive the Windows 11 update. " Why do you think MS is rolling out Windows 11, to everyone? See https://www.cnet.com/tech/services-and-software/windows-11-is-finally-here-but-not-everyone-will-get-microsofts-new-os-today-what-to-know/ . And why would you **want** to force your PC to run an OS that would not be suitable?

Comment: I've installed on a laptop without TPM at all. TPM is only needed for bitlocker. My machine is made in 2012. Win11 seems to work faster than Win8.1

Comment: @DrMoishePippik it would be suitable well, except the bitlocker feature.